# Вопрос по Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Как лучше всего распределить пользователей в Django?
Например, есть пользователи студенты у которых есть свои отдельные профили, страницы и др. Другие пользователи Деканат у них отдельный профиль и доступ к другим страничкам . И преподаватели у них тоже есть странички которые не могут посмотреть студенты и деканат.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Просто сделать три отдельных сайта?

Comment: Надо иметь общие модели

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать OneToOne relation:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    # общие поля для всех пользователей

class Student(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ... 
     # поля только для студента

class Teacher(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ... 
     # поля только для учителя

class Dean(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ... 
     # поля только для деканов
```